# can we choose/modify where readLine() method starts reading?

Tags: java, io, readline

I searched through all the topics and since I couldn't find a similar problem, I'd like to ask the following question:

given the sample code:

```
try (BufferedReader helpRdr= new BufferedReader (new FileReader (helpfile))){

        do {
                                    //read characters until # is found
        ch= helpRdr.read();
                                    //now see if topics match
        if (ch=='#') {

            topic= helpRdr.readLine();
            if (what.compareTo(topic)==0) {                     //found topic

                do {

                    info=helpRdr.readLine();
                    if (info!=null) System.out.println (info);
                } while ((info!=null) && (info.compareTo("")!=0));
```

and a sample file content:

> "#if
>   if (condition) statement;
>   else statement;
>   "

**The question is:**

why does readLine() method in the above example doesn't read '#',  instead having the following output:if (condition) statement; else statement;

Thanks for help in advance folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you have already *read* the `#` character and therefore is no longer there when you do `read()` or `readLine()`.

What you can do is this:

```
String ch = helpRdr.readLine();
if (ch.startsWith("#")) {
 // Do your stuff
}
```

Or this:

```
topic = ch + helpRdr.readLine();
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, great answer, one more question though: you said that: " you have already read the # character and therefore is no longer there"- may I ask where? some kind of heap or what?

Comment: With `helpRdr.read()` you already read the character `#` from the `BufferedReader`. looking at [jdk8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/io/BufferedReader.java) you can see that `nextChar` is increased which determines what the start position is when you do `read` or `readLine` etc. So next time the start position is `1` higher and you won't get the `#` character anymore